# Load JSON file to BigQuery with empty dict as a value

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am uploading a newline-delimited JSON file from GCS to BigQuery. There are some fields in the JSON file which contain dicts for values, and I have no problem getting those values into BigQuery, as the nested fields are broken down into separate columns. So it all works if the following example is a line from the JSON file:

`{"dict_field": {"value1": 1, "value2": 2}}`

However, if one line from the file has an empty dict as the value for *field_dict*, like this:

`{"dict_field": {}}`

I get the following error message:

> Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {'reason': 'invalid', 'message': "Unsupported empty struct type for field 'dict_field'"} [...]

I looked through the BigQuery documentation and couldn't find any stated restriction regarding empty dicts as values. Does anyone know if there is a workaround to this issue, or if I have to manually clean the data before importing it in BigQuery?

Comment: I think your question might be related with this feature request `https://issuetracker.google.com/130890049`

Comment: Can you share the code and the option that you send to BigQuery with you submit the dict?

Comment: BigQuery doesn't currently support loading JSON data with empty structures. There are no workarounds besides removing the empty structures from your JSON data. If you're using any programming language you can iterate through your JSON data and replace empty structures "{}" with "null" values. Other than that, the only option left is to follow up in the [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/130890049) that has been shared above for any possible updates about implementing support for empty structures when loading JSON data in BigQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out by @rodvictor and @Fcojavmelo, loading empty dicts from JSON files isn't currently possible although it' not explicitly mentioned anywhere in the BigQuery documentation, only in this [issue/feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/130890049).

In conclusion, the data has to be manually cleaned, and any empty dicts removed to avoid errors.

Answer (score 2):

Wild that this isn't documented, thanks to this answer I was reassured I wasn't taking crazy pills.

In my situation, I am attempting to load Shopify data into BigQuery from Python. This recursive function helped clear up empty dicts by replacing them with `None`:

```
def replace_blank_dict(d):
    if not d:
        return None
    if type(d) is list:
        for list_item in d:
            if type(list_item) is dict:
                for k, v in list_item.items():
                    list_item[k] = replace_blank_dict(v)
    if type(d) is dict:
        for k, v in d.items():
            d[k] = replace_blank_dict(v)
    return d
```

Called as such, when looping through a list of [Orders from the Shopify REST API](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order#index-2021-01):

```
    for order in orders:
        for k, v in order.items():
            order[k] = replace_blank_dict(v)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am currently dealing with Shopify orders data and import to bigquery and I didnt expect I will find exact solution for this problem!